# Setting the indents in bibliography

Tags: indentation

I want to set the indent of the first (1) and the second (2) (third..) line. In addition, setting the space (3) between first and second cite. Is it possible? Thank you.

[image: indent]

My MWE is here:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{einstein,
    author = "Albert Einstein",
    title = "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal = "Annalen der Physik",
    volume = "322",
    number = "10",
    pages = "891--921",
    year = "1905",
    DOI = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
    keywords = "physics"
}

@book{dirac,
    title = {The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author = {Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn = {9780198520115},
    series = {International series of monographs on physics},
    year = {1981},
    publisher = {Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {physics}
}

@online{knuthwebsite,
    author = "Donald Knuth",
    title = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url  = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
    addendum = "(accessed: 01.09.2016)",
    keywords = "latex,knuth"
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=turkish,english,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titlesec}


% Customize headings
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand*{\myonevspace}{13.850574pt}% <-- Define a macro \myonehalfvspace
\newcommand*{\myonehalfvspace}{20.775861pt}% <-- Define a macro \myonehalfvspace
\newcommand*{\mytwovspace}{27.701147pt}% <-- Define a macro \mytwovspace

% Chapter heading \titlespacing*{command}{left}{before-sep}{after-sep}[right-sep]
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{1cm}{0cm plus 4pt minus 2pt}{\myonehalfvspace plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % or some other suitable bib style

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage[spaces,obeyspaces,hyphens]{xurl} % allow arbitrary line breaks in URL strings
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}

Chapter name and the first line of the paragraph is aligned here \cite{einstein}, \cite{dirac}, \cite{knuthwebsite}.

\setlength\bibhang{50pt}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496456/adjust-vertical-and-horizontal-alignments-in-multicolumn-bibliography#comment1253407_496456

Comment: @user191173 - I don't think the queries are meaningfully related. The link you provided points to a query that uses the `biblatex` package, whereas the present query uses the `natbib` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've indicated that you use the `natbib` package as well as (somewhat implicitly) an author-year citation call-out style.

Excerpting from section 2.12, "Other formatting options" (pp. 15f.) of the user guide of `natbib` package:

> `\bibhang` The list of references for author-year styles uses a hanging indentation
>   format: the first line of each reference is flush left, the following lines are
>   set with an indentation from the left margin. This indentation is `1em` by
>   default but may be changed by redefining (with `\setlength`) the length
>   parameter `\bibhang`.
>
> `\bibsep` The vertical spacing between references in the list, whether author-year or numerical, is controlled by the length `\bibsep`. If this is set to `0pt`, there is no extra line spacing between references. The default spacing depends
>   on the font size selected in `\documentclass`, and is almost a full blank line.
>   Change this by redefining `\bibsep` with `\setlength` command.

Coming back to your questions:

1. To modify the amount of indentation of the first line, `natbib` offers no special facilities as authoryear-style citation call-outs are being used. Since this citation style has no need for numbers, there's no need to modify the indentation of the first line of the formatted bibliographic item.

   If you really need to modify the amount of indentation of the first line, you'd have to modify some low-level LaTeX parameters that govern the amount of indentation of the first line of a paragraph. Please advise if this is actually a priority for you. (Speaking for myself, I'd find any amount of non-zero indentation to be rather odd-looking.)
2. To modify the amount of hanging indentation in a paragraph, change the parameter `\bibhang` via a `\setlength` statement. E.g., `\setlength\bibhang{0pt}` directs LaTeX *not* to create a hanging indentation.
3. The default value of `\bibsep` is -- since the `12pt` document class option is in effect -- `10pt plus 5pt minus 2pt`. Note that is a "rubber length" in TeX parlance. The mild stretchability and shrinkability is actually a nice feature, especially if `\flushbottom` is in effect. To change this parameter to a fixed (i.e., non-strechable and non-shrinkable) length, issue a statement such as `\setlength{\bibsep}{1\baselineskip}`. (For the `12pt` document class option, `1\baselineskip` amounts to `14.5pt`.)

Comment: Thank you @Mico Second and third problems are solved thanks to you. First problem is exactly: bibliography text must start at the chapter name's alignment. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSzzt.jpg  It starts in MWE but in the overleaf project it is not.

Comment: @volkan - There must be something in your document's code that creates a *negative indent* for the first line of the bib entries. Not knowing what this code might be, I'm afraid I have no idea how to go about fixing the issue. I can only suggest that you create a new query in which you focus on just this one issue and provide all necessary information.

Comment: In fact, the negative indent is created consciously to obeying thesis rules. Without making any changes for chapter names, I have to set the indent of the cite’s first line. Under the circumstances, have you any advice?

Comment: @volkan - Without knowledge of how the “thesis rules” are translated into LaTeX code, I can’t offer any further advice.

Comment: The chapter (section, subsection...) title must have 1 cm indent. And cite's first line must start at the chapter name's alignment. I updated MWE in my question. There are the codes that run the chapter name's indent. In terms of giving an idea, I'd appreciate it if you could browse.